# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist error using Selenium ChromeDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing *java.lang.IllegalStateException* executing my code.

Code trials:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class seleniumintroduction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ATIF\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Selenium Course\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
 }
```

Error I'm seeing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\Users\ATIF\OneDrive\Desktop\Selenium Course\chromedriver_win32.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the downloaded zip file name is *chromedriver_win32.zip*, but once you extract the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) it's ***chromedriver.exe***

[image: ChromeDriverExecutable]

So you need to change the line:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ATIF\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Selenium Course\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
```

as

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\ATIF\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Selenium Course\\chromedriver.exe");
```